# namespace doesn't get resolved properly Android.Support.V4.App.ListFragment

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm working on xamarin.android and I get this error when a package downloaded a dependent package with existing class

```
public class DeliveriesFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.ListFragment
    {
        public override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

as you can see I fully typed the class with its namespace

```
Android.Support.V4.App.ListFragment
```

but I still get this error

```
The type 'ListFragment' exists in both 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

any idea how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Import this namespace `using listFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.ListFragment;` and inherit your class like this `DeliveriesFragment : listFragment`

Comment: the error will point to this line `using listFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.ListFragment`

Comment: Will point or pointing? uninstall `Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment`.

Comment: that's the problem `Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment` is required on the package that I've added. I just remove the package that requires it and removed it. Thanks